# How to uninstall/remove openproject completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, version, uninstallation, openproject

I have followed `openproject.org` and installed with latest version `12`. But I want to check some feature in version `10`. So I tried removing by `sudo apt-get remove openproject` and reinstalled with 10. While configure it getting an error like,

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "updated_on" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT MAX(updated_on) FROM "settings"
```

Not sure why this error is throwing. So I thought to remove openproject again completely. Please confirm the above command is enough to do this or anything else I need to do.

Comment: The reason for this is that the database schema which is at a 12.x state now does not match the schema expected for 10.x. You would need to drop the database (if it does not contain any valuable data) before reinstalling.